# How to achieve desired video background

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, background

The background image for my site is quite similar to http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/La_Gran_Sabana.jpg

I'd like to make the clouds move and give the appearance of as if the viewer were actually on a hilltop peering out into the valley. What program or process would be required to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: I have no idea how :/ wasn't sure what the best approach would be so at this point I'd just like to know what program it would take to get this effect.

To answer your question, I haven't tried anything yet because I wouldn't know where to start really.

Comment: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/07/cinemagraphs.html - check this out

Comment: You'd have to have separate cloud images that you animate. To animate them you could use CSS animations, Canvas + Javascript, Flash, Adobe Edge Animate and more. Or you could use an animated GIF, but those tend to be choppy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a full video background of clouds moving and then put a .png image of the ground together with the hills over it and set the position to bottom. Fiddle on the way.

EDIT: Making a fiddle with a custom video was somehow problematic, so I created a simple website to show the solution: http://alweso.2ap.pl/sky/index.html

HTML:

```
<video autoplay loop id="bgvid">
<source src="sky.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="sky.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<img id="ground" src="ground.png">
```

CSS:

```
video#bgvid { 
position: fixed; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; 
min-height: 100%;
width: auto; 
height: auto; 
z-index: -100;
background-size: cover; 
}

#ground {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

The sky from the image should be of course cut out more carefully (I recommend Photoshop) and the video obviously doesn't match the colours of the picture, but I think the website shows the general idea.